# Progress bar Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Uso o `$http` do angular JS para trabalhar com web-services, alguém sabe me dizer como conseguir criar um progressbar usando esse metodo?

```
$http.get( "json.php?action=3"
      + "&id=" + id
      + "&val=" + $("#v"+id).val()
      + "&ajax_select_tab=" + ajax_select_tab
      + "&ajax_where=" + ajax_where ).then(function (result) {

      if (result.status === 200) {

          var chave = rows_.indexOf(ajax_select_tab[1]);
          $scope
              .rows[chave]["array_selec_data"] = result.data;
       } else {
            alert("Erro ao carregar o arquivo JSON!");
       }
});
```

queria usar a progress bar do bootstrap, mas não consigo um metodo que faça o ajax e retorne o flush da requisição.

Comment: Voce quer que ela mostre um progresso de X% ou apenas aquelas "Carregando" onde não existe acompanhamento do quanto foi processado?

Comment: Preciso da porcentagem pra popular a progress bar

Comment: Creio que do jeito que está estrurado sua requisição isso não será possível, pois não se tem controle do que está sendo processado no servidor, para isso voce teria que ter notificações push passando o estado do que está sendo executado no server side... O que poderia ser feito é colocar aquela barra de "processando"

Answer (score 0):

Implemente um *interceptor*. Da [documentação original](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors):

> Os *interceptors* são *service factories* que são registradas com o provedor `$http`, via adição ao array `$httpProvider.interceptors`. A *factory* é chamada e injetada com dependências (se alguma for especificada) e retorna o interceptador.

Basicamente você pode utilizar *interceptors* para várias tarefas globais que envolvam o provedor `$http` - por exemplo autenticação, ou geração de loading spinners independente do *endpoint* chamado.

Este processo funciona bem se você precisar apenas saber se uma chamada terminou ou não.

Para saber a que fração está o seu processo é necessário que você saiba o tamanho final. Em envios/receptação de arquivos isso é fácil porque os cabeçalhos HTTP indicam o tamanho. Entretanto em um processo customizado você precisa gerar este cabeçalho, ou um *endpoint* que reporte o estado atual de processamento.

[Exemplo de implementacão (SO em Inglês).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850865/1845714)